# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while configuring dpkg

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I was trying to force install the picoscenes drive via

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i /var/cache/apt/archives/picoscenes-driver-modules-5.15.0-78-generic_20230803_amd64.deb
```

and in the process may have broken my dpkg installer, given I am quite new to Linux systems I am not sure how to navigate this, so far I have tried.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/picoscenes-driver-modules-5.15.0-78-generic_20230803_amd64.deb
```

Followed by `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt install -f` which gives my a long list of problems.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool linux-headers-5.15.0-83-generic
  linux-headers-5.4.0-162 linux-headers-5.4.0-162-lowlatency
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-lowlatency
  linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-83 linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-83-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-83-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-162-lowlatency thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic (5.15.0-78.85~20.04.1) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-78-generic
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-83-generic (5.15.0-83.92~20.04.1) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-83-generic
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic (5.15.0-73.80~20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-155-lowlatency (5.4.0-155.172) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-131-lowlatency
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-131-lowlatency with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic (5.15.0-78.85~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-78-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-78-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic package post-installation script subpro
cess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-83-generic (5.15.0-83.92~20.
04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-83-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-83-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-83-generic (--configu
re):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-83-generic package post-installation scri
pt subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic (5.15.0-73.80~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-73-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-73-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic package post-installation script subpro
cess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing trigger
s for linux-image-5.4.0-155-lowlatency (5.4.0-155.172) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-155-lowlatency
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-155-lowlatency with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-155-lowlatency (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-155-lowlatency package post-installation script sub
process returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encoun
tered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-83-generic
 linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic
 linux-image-5.4.0-155-lowlatency
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Realizing there is a problem with the intramfs-tools and Linux kernel images, I tried

```
sudo apt remove initramfs-tools
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install initramfs-tools
```

And then looking for obsolete linux images via `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` and removing them, follwed by `sudo apt install-f`, which brings me back to with the same error.

Distribution and version information

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

Update:
I realized that I need to remove the configuration files in order to completely remove the linux images for example

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-5.4.0-152-lowlatency
```

Fixed some of the issues, the final issue remains with the initramfs-tools. I have tried purging, followed by reinstalling but that gives me the error

```
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt purge util-linux && sudo apt install util-linux` which purges and reinstalls the package that provides fsck.